# How to check if any one value not equals and stop calling function within each function using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the given code, if any of the input value not equal to the attribute value,it returns false and dont call the function "printDiv()".This printDiv function for window.print().Now if each function fails also calling printdiv after print page opens in another windows then only error alert message showing.If any one the value fails within each function only want to show alert message and dont call printdiv function

How to fix this issue?

```
 $("#btnprint").click(function(e) {
        var isValid = true;
        $('#printcontent').hide();
        var orginaladv = $('#orginal_advamt').val();
        var orginalbal = $('#orginal_balamt').val();
        var changeadv = $('#advamt').val();
        var changebal = $('#balamt').val();

        $('.checkattrval').each(function() {
             e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).val() != $(this).attr('data-orgval')) {
                alert("You should update first");
                isValid = false;
                return false;
            }
             else {
                 printDiv(); 
             }
        });
        return isValid;
    });
```

Comment: well you need to check/call it outside of the loop, not inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the call to `printDiv()` outside the loop, and have it check `isValid` there. Otherwise you call it for each valid field until you get to an invalid one.

```
$("#btnprint").click(function(e) {
  var isValid = true;
  $('#printcontent').hide();
  var orginaladv = $('#orginal_advamt').val();
  var orginalbal = $('#orginal_balamt').val();
  var changeadv = $('#advamt').val();
  var changebal = $('#balamt').val();

  $('.checkattrval').each(function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).val() != $(this).attr('data-orgval')) {
      alert("You should update first");
      isValid = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (isValid) {
    printDiv();
  }
});
```